# Why is my water main pipe curved at the meter

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, meter

I wonder why the connection from my house to the water meter is curved, and is it OK to replace it with a straight line?

[image: pic2]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be replaced?

Comment: That looks like lead pipe. Scratch it to find out.

Comment: "The San Francisco Public Utilities Commission and East Bay Municipal Utility District replaced *their* lead water pipes in the 1980s." - doesn't mean the pipe in *your* yard isn't still.

Comment: I'm losing 5k gallons every 15 hours. I need to replace it myself since I was quoted $3500 for a spot repair and $7400 for total replacement for the line to my house.  It's about 25 feet long under rocks abd dirt in my backyard.  I can't afford that. Plus $3500.. I'd rather educate and replace it myself.

Comment: I live in Sacramento.   Pretty sure it's copper due to the color. May not show in the pic.

Comment: I think the extreme rain we've had after many years of drought and now that it has gotten cold enough to hail caused the pipe to freeze... but the warranty won't cover it and neither will our insurance because they claim it's because they're just old pipes.

Comment: If you were losing water before it was metered, the company would not be charging you for it. So this isn't the point of failure. Start turning off valves until the meter stops (or at least slows down) and then figure out where that one goes. Repeat until you've isolated the problem. Fix it, see if the leak has stopped. If not, find the next leak. Any sign of water in basement, or around house? In-ground sprinkler system you didn't drain?

Comment: (if your concern is the leak, you've asked the wrong question. Start by looking at how to find a leak. There are some good existing answers on that topic.)

Answer (score 7):

Two reasons come to mind.

First, the bend allows for some longitudinal expansion and contraction of the pipe to be accommodated.  Sort of like the serpentine routing of the Alaskan pipeline.  Picture from the USGS.

[image]

Second, the bend makes it easier to connect the pipe to the meter, which would almost impossible with a rigid, fixed length pipe and fixed meter location.

Comment: Do you think it was tonlower the line deeper without using a 90 degree angle? Thus the water flows smoother vs a sharp turn?  Or do sharp angles not really matter?

Comment: Also I added another picture.  After some more digging...the pipe connection is S shaped (I think to go lower into the ground below frost line) but also where the yellow arrow points is another section that goes back out...the opposite direction of my house. I can't figure out if that is some type of clamp to hold it in place, another pipe that my neighbor connected to use for his pool , or what?? I can't check more as it started HAILING in Sacramento. ‍♂️. Not a common thing.

Comment: There are lots of 90 degree turns in your house's plumbing. Yes, there may be a bit of turbulence and reduction of maximum flow rate, but generally not enough to matter. You're rarely running at full flow rate anyway. (My own water makes a 90 degree turn right before the meter.)

Comment: The curves are better than right angle bends from a pressure drop standpoint.  But I think that was secondary to the other reasons I mentioned.  Note that the curved assembly is most likely a purchased item, and most of the costs of assembling that is in the labor.  So cost is probably a none issue.

Comment: Cool pic! I've actually touched the Alaska Pipeline! Well, a hand-sized bit of it. Quite the engineering feat! `</off-topic comment>`

Answer (score 2):

#### What's that thing the meter is connected to??

You're looking at the water meter yoke assembly. Don't attempt to modify or replace it; it's the property of the water supplier. Their pipe connects to the side with the valve (lower-left in the photo below); your pipe connects to the opposite side. (photo from [www.ferguson.com](http://www.ferguson.com))

[image: water meter yoke assembly]

The yoke makes installation and maintenance of a water connection easier:

- it holds the meter closer to the ground surface for easy reading, while letting the piping remain deeper for protection against freezing or damage.
- at time of new construction yoke is installed while trenches are open; the meter is held back until the customer is ready to have service turned on. This protects the expensive meter from damage and also deters water theft.
- at some point in the future the water meter will need to be replaced because it's damaged, time for an upgrade, or whatever. The yoke makes it easy to do this.
- The yoke has a built-in stop valve for shutting off (and locking off) service.
- The bracing at the bottom of the yoke protects the meter from any longitudinal stress that would occur if the piping contracts lengthwise or is pulled (for example by an excavator striking and grabbing the pipe somewhere near by).

#### Got any tips for DIY replacing my water main?

In most places copper tube ($$$$), HDPE poly tube, and PEX are accepted for direct-bury potable water main use. PEX and copper along with their fittings are easy to obtain at most home improvement stores. HDPE, however, is most commonly used by professionals for probably the last 25 years or so. I've never heard of restrictions for a non-plumber to purchase HDPE and the associated fittings, but you'll have to find a waterworks plumbing supply house that carries them.

You'll notice the fitting at the bottom of the yoke, where your privately-owned water main pipe attaches, is some weird thing you've never seen in the plumbing aisle. If you could determine the make of the meter yoke then you could get (from the waterworks plumbing supply house) an adapter to your preferred kind of pipe. It's more convenient to leave a stub of whatever pipe is there now and adapt it to the kind of pipe you want to install. If the existing is copper and you're going to install PEX then there are two options: direct copper sweat to PEX barb, or copper sweat to pipe thread, then pipe thread to PEX barb.

The pro plumber's bids give you LOTS of latitude to employ some tools, even if you have to rent or buy them, while still saving a heap of cash. Call a few tool rental centers, tell them about your project, soil type, and obstacles you need to deal with (other buried utilities, retaining walls, vegetation, etc) and ask what equipment they offer that might help you with the job.

Answer (score 0):

The connection from your house to the water meter is likely curved to avoid any debris or other material that may be in the ground from blocking the water flow. You may be able to replace the line with a straight line, but it is best to contact a plumber or other professional to ensure that the line is installed correctly and safely.